# Laravel 5.2 Undefined variable (select drop down)

Tags: laravel, select

This is the function to return the rows from the database in my InfoController

```
protected function getInfo()
{
    $info = Info::where('status', '1')->orderBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');

    return view('registration.profile')->with('info', $info);

}
```

Index method in InfoController

```
public function index()
{
    return view('register/profile');
}
```

In my view

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'info')) !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('Info','Select an Option'), array('class' => 'col-md-4
                        control-label') }}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          {!! Form::select('Info', $info, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('pronunciation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('pronunciation', 'Pronunciation', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('pronunciation', old('pronunciation'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('pronunciation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('pronunciation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                        {{ Form::label('dob', 'Date of Birth', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('dob', old('dob'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('dob'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phonePrimary') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('phonePrimary', 'Primary Phone Number', array('class' => 'col-md-4
                        control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('phonePrimary', old('phonePrimary'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('phonePrimary'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('phonePrimary') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phoneSecondary') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('phoneSecondary', 'Secondary Phone Number', array('class' => 'col-md-4
                        control-label')
                        ) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::text('phoneSecondary', old('phoneSecondary'), array('class' =>'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => 'xxx-xxx-xxxx')) }}
                        @if ($errors->has('phoneSecondary'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('phoneSecondary') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressLineOne') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressLineOne', 'Address Line One', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressLineOne', old('addressLineOne'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressLineOne'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressLineOne') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressLineTwo') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressLineTwo', 'Address Line Two', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressLineTwo', old('addressLineTwo'), array('class' =>
                            'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressLineTwo'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressLineTwo') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressProv') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressProv', 'Province', array('class' => 'col-md-4
                        control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressProv', old('addressProv'), array('class' =>'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressProv'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressProv') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressProvOther') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressProvOther', 'Other Province', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressProvOther', old('addressProvOther'), array('class' =>'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressProvOther'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressProvOther') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressCountry') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressCountry', 'Country', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressCountry', old('addressCountry'), array('class' =>'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressCountry'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressCountry') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('addressCountryOther') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('addressCountryOther', 'Other Country', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('addressCountryOther', old('addressCountryOther'), array('class' =>'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('addressCountryOther'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('addressCountryOther') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emergencyRelationship') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('emergencyRelationship', 'Relationship to Contact', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('emergencyRelationship', old('emergencyRelationship'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('emergencyRelationship'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('emergencyRelationship') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emergencyContact') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('emergencyContact', 'Name of Emergency Contact', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('emergencyContact', old('emergencyContact'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('emergencyContact'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('emergencyContact') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emergencyNumber') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('emergencyNumber', 'Contacts Phone Number', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('emergencyNumber', old('emergencyNumber'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('emergencyNumber'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('emergencyNumber') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emergencyRelationship') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        {{ Form::label('emergencyRelationship', 'Relationship to Contact', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('emergencyRelationship', old('emergencyRelationship'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            @if ($errors->has('emergencyRelationship'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('emergencyRelationship') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('notes', 'Notes', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ Form::text('notes', old('notes'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here are all my routes from route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('/welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::resource('dept', 'DeptController');

Route::resource('info', 'InfoController');

Route::get('info', 'InfoController@getInfo');

Route::resource('userInfo', 'UserInfoController');

Route::resource('hc', 'HCController');

Route::resource('events', 'EventsController');
```

The Info table has over 10 entries with status = 1

Here are the errors I am getting.. They are too big to paste here

Error 2/2 
http://pastebin.com/8qqA73A6
    ErrorException in ec2da5a708f4be6fbaacda062c4e3a98ce5eb42c.php line   24: Undefined variable: info (View: ......)

Error 1/2 
http://pastebin.com/rysZvcCt

```
ErrorException in ec2da5a708f4be6fbaacda062c4e3a98ce5eb42c.php line 24: Undefined variable: info
```

Comment: `lists()` is deprecated, you should use `pluck()` instead.

Comment: Can You give exact error You get?

Comment: add your routes file, full error and view code

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I added all of it.

Comment: @GiedriusKirsys I have added the error I am getting

Comment: @michealb Somehow I believe that this is just a silly mistake. You don't have route to `getInfo` method, so maybe You actually accessing other route where same view returned, but without passing `$info` to it?

Comment: @GiedriusKirsys That was my mistake. I corrected it. There is a getInfo route

Comment: @michealb Please show Your `InfoController` `index` method content.

Comment: @GiedriusKirsys I added it

Comment: @michealb Are You sure, that that exact method is being fired, when error occurs? Check it with `dd($info);`. I bet, that You are trying to access different method in controller, because everything is just fine with Your provided code.

Comment: @giedriuskirsys where should I output it?

Answer (score 1):

You are ending your Form::label too soon

```
{{ Form::label('Info','Select an Option'), array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label') }}
```

should be

```
{{ Form::label('Info','Select an Option', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
```

Comment: I just changed it and it still is giving me the same error that info variable is undefined

Comment: can you go into storage/framework/views/ec2da5a708f4be6fbaacda062c4e3a98ce5eb42c.php and post lines 20 to 25 of that file?  (it will show the real php code)

Comment: I just checked and line 20-25 is my Form::select drop down `<div class="col-md-6">
                          {!! Form::select('Info', $info, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        </div>
                    </div>`

Comment: I mean the compiled version.  see my previous comment on what file to actually open via the console or whatever you are using.

Comment: Here you go `<?php echo e(Form::label('info','Select a Option', array('class'
            => 'col-md-4 control-label')
        )); ?>
            <?php echo Form::select('info', $info, null, ['class' => 
                'form-control']); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade

Comment: Actually no. `lists` still available, just it is deprecated now, since `pluck` do the same thing. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L453 So the problem here is not in `lists` method usage.

Answer (score 0):

`with` flashes session data, it does not expose variables with the given name.
 When doing things this way, your data will be available in your view like this:

```
session('info')
```

What you actually want is this:

```
protected function getInfo()
{
    $info = Info::where('status', '1')->orderBy('name')->lists('name', 'id');
    return view('registration.profile', ['info' => $info]);
}
```

Comment: I changed my getInfo function to match yours. In my profile view at the top of the file I added `session('info') but I still get the undefined variable error